# Select a subsample of columns when reading a file in the tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, readr

I would like to read a csv file selecting only a subsetting of the available columns. Usually I used to perfom this kind of process using the `fread` function of the `data.table` package. I could use `read_csv` and then select only the columns of interest but I want to do the selection when I read the file.

Is that possible? Have I missed some `read_csv` options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `col_types()` argument of `read_csv()`, passing `cols_only()` with the columns you need and their type (also guessable):

```
read_csv('loadTest.csv', 
         col_types = cols_only('col1' = col_integer(), #col1 is integer
                               'col2' = 'c',           #col2 is character
                               'col8' = col_guess()    #guess type
                               'col10' = '?'           #guess type
                               )
)
```